# Load images in background thread or UI thread?

Tags: android, picasso

My android app has a `ListView` which fetches a set of image urls from the web in the background and then passes this to the UI thread. The UI thread then downloads the images and displays them (I'm using `Picasso` for the same to ensure caching and resizing.)

I would like to know if I should download the images in the background thread and then pass only the resized bitmaps to the UI thread for display. Also, what happens when the user scrolls the screen in both the scenarios - do all images get retrieved from the web again? I'm not able to understand which would be faster in this case. The app is very similar to the Facebook android app.

One more thing - My app would refresh every 5 minutes and if there is any new image url in the list, it would restart the entire process starting from the background thread. My idea is that since the earlier images would have cached, they will not be loaded again. Only the new urls will be loaded. Is this correct?

Comment: Similar to Facebook app - this is good one ;)

Comment: Similar to how facebook loads images. I would like to know how does scrolling in the list view work for apps like facebook - do they load images in the background and cache it to disk/memory? And what happens when we fetch new posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The UI thread then downloads the images and displays them (I'm using Picasso for the same to ensure caching and resizing.)

Picasso does not download the images on the main application thread by default. I'm not even sure that there is an option to do that.

> I would like to know if I should download the images in the background thread and then pass only the resized bitmaps to the UI thread for display.

Picasso should be doing that for you.

> Also, what happens when the user scrolls the screen in both the scenarios - do all images get retrieved from the web again?

That depends on how many images, how big they are, the size of the cache, and so forth. Picasso gives you options for determining how this is behaving, from debug indicators in the corners to indicate the image source (`setIndicatorsEnabled(true)`) to getting a `StatsSnapshot` to tell you how your caching is performing (`getSnapshot()`).

Comment: Thanks! Suppose I scroll down in the app and then decide to go the top of the app with one click. What is the best way to handle such a case?

Comment: @PranavSodhani: Sorry, but I do not understand the question.

Comment: Okay! let me try again. In my app, I would load 10 images initially when the user starts the app. The user can go till the bottom of the screen, post which I will load 10 more images and this should continue - similar to how posts are loaded in facebook.

Now suppose the user wants to get to the top of the screen i.e. scroll to the top in one click. What is the best way to handle this? I assume that as new images will be loaded - picasso will remove the old ones from cache but now since the user should see old images - how does it work?

Comment: @PranavSodhani: "I assume that as new images will be loaded - picasso will remove the old ones from cache but now since the user should see old images - how does it work?" -- either the images are in the cache, or they are not. Picasso handles it automatically, either way. Other than tuning the cache to be an appropriate size (given all the other considerations for your app), there is nothing for you to do.

Comment: Sounds logical. Thanks. Would like to from someone if they how facebook app handles this.

Answer (score 0):

All network operations runs in background in Android, Picasso not an exception. When you scroll your list, Picasso check it cache, if there is no particular image in cache, it downloads it.